# ghc-mod info only works for main

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-mod

So I have a very basic haskell file that looks like this :

```
main = thing
thing = print "hi"
```

When I run the ghc-mod command to get info on the main function like this : 'ghc-mod info file.hs main', I get the proper result :

main :: IO ()   -- Defined at file.hs:1:1

But then if I try 'ghc-mod info file.hs thing', it doesn't output anything at all, not even a blank line or error. I have version 5.2.0.0 of ghc-mod, and version 7.8.3 of GHC. How can I get ghc-mod info to work?

Comment: If you have no module name, it is `module Main (main) where`, so main is the only visible thing it can check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `ghc-mod` needs you to put a `module Something where` at the beginning of your source file in order to work correctly.

Comment: Of course, after spending hours trying to figure it out and reinstalling haskell, ghc-mod, vim, etc., it's a one line fix... Thanks!